# Cygwin Diff -y output to text file poorly formatted

Tags: cygwin, diff

I am using cygwin to create a side-by-side diff to text files. However when simply doing `diff -y SomeFile SomeOtherFile > diffresult.txt` the resulting textfile has no linebreaks when opened in windows, and when opened in vim the indentation makes it incredibly hard to read.

Is it possibly to reformat the output and keep it readable in a non-manual way?
I have tried to utilize unix2dos and dos2unix, in hopes that it was a cygwin messing with the spacing, however those had useful effect.

Comment: Pipe the output through u2d. I.e.. `diff -y SomeFile SomeOtherFile | u2d > diffresult.txt`. Also try adjusting the output width to avoid line truncation or wrapping.

Comment: have the starting files LF linebreaks or CRLF ? diff assume both have LF only